# Python Ctypes Access Violation Writing

Tags: python, python-3.x

He estado intentando configurar algunos datos en un dispositivo utilizando el SDK proporcionado por el fabricante (ZKTECO). Algunas funciones, como conectar, desconectar, modificar la dirección IP, funcionan sin problemas, pero cuando intento actualizar los datos a una tabla interna, aparece el siguiente error: `exception: access violation writing 0x000000000205A040` en la linea `ret = zk.SetDeviceData(handler, table, data, options)` . A partir de lo que he investigado, el problema más común tiene que ver con establecer los *argtypes* y *restypes* correctos, que he aplicado a mi entendimiento. Como información adicional, estoy usando python 3.7 junto con Windows 10 pro 64-bit.

Funciónes del documento:

```
int SetDeviceData (HANDLE handle, const char * TableName, const char * Data, const char * Options)

int Connect (const char *Parameters)

Void Disconnect(HANDLE handle)
```

Código que tengo hasta ahora:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import cdll, windll, create_string_buffer, c_char_p, c_void_p
from ctypes.wintypes import HANDLE

zk = windll.LoadLibrary("C:/Windows/System32/plcommpro.dll")

zk.Connect.argtypes = [c_char_p]
zk.Connect.restype = HANDLE

zk.SetDeviceData.argtypes = (HANDLE, c_char_p, c_char_p, c_char_p)
zk.SetDeviceData.restypes = ctypes.c_int

zk.Disconnect.argtypes = [HANDLE]
zk.Disconnect.restypes = c_void_p

params = b"protocol=TCP,ipaddress=192.168.100.178,port=4370,timeout=5000,passwd="

handler = zk.Connect(params)

string = "Handler is: {0}\n".format(handler)
print(string)

table = b"user"
data = b"CardNo=\tPin=9999\tPassword=1793\tName=Test\tStartTime=20181212\tEndTime=20181222"
options = b""

ret = zk.SetDeviceData(handler, table, data, options)

result = "Result: {0}".format(ret)
print(result)


zk.Disconnect(handler)
handler = 0
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmpdll.py", line 35, in <module>
    ret = zk.SetDeviceData(handler, table, data, options)
OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x000000005EF65040
```

Comment: prueba actualizando tus setuptools `pip install setuptools numpy scipy scikit-learn -U`

Comment: Los actualize pero el problema persiste